# <RandomizedSearchCV> Pass the estimator obtained after fitting to scoring function as a parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Suppose I want to do a RandomizedSearchCV with custom both estimator and scorer :

```
RandomizedSearchCV(cxCustomLogReg(), search_space,
                   n_iter=50, scoring=scorer)
```

May it be possible, during randomized search, to pass the estimator obtained after fitting `cxCustomLogReg()` to `scorer` function as a parameter (and not only `y_true`/`y_pred` values as usual)?

Comment: As written, your question is asking whether you can pass the variable `random_search` to a function. Assuming the code you've written runs, the answer to that question is yes, but it seems like you already know that.  My guess is that the code you've written doesn't work. Can you try re-writing your question so that we can help you with your actual problem?

Comment: Scoring function ('scorer') within RandomizedSearchCV() uses predictions of fitted estimator ('cxCustomLogReg') on each fold to assess a performance metric. Though, in my custom 'scorer' I need not only predictions but also the fitted function to do custom analysis.

Comment: @Chris I'll delete the word 'random_search' to avoid any confusion. I refer strictly to the randomized search process.

Comment: That isn't the source of confusion. Check your sentence that starts with "may it be possible" (Is it possible).

Comment: What is your custom scorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the expected format. When `scoring` is a callable, it should have signature `(fitted_estimator, X_test, y_test)`.

You may be using the helper `make_scorer`, which converts a metric function with signature `(y_true, y_pred)` into a scoring function as described above. Just don't use that helper, and define your scorer directly.